# What is the default [minimumvolume] for the /playsound command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is the syntax for the `/playsound` command in Minecraft:

```
/playsound (sound) (source) (player) [x] [y] [z] [volume] [pitch] [minimumvolume]
```

The `[volume]`, `[pitch]`, and `[minimumvolume]` parameters are automatically set to their defaults if left blank upon execution.

The default for `[volume]` and `[pitch]` are both 1. What is the default for `[minimumvolume]`?

Comment: From the wiki (https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#playsound) it sounds to me like that argument would be used for server-wide sounds (like dragon death or wither creation). Then its standard should be 0. But I don't really have experience with that command.

Comment: it couldn't be 0 because [minimumvolume] is the actual loudness of the sound. I know it's confusing since there is a [volume] parameter, but it's use to determine how far the sound travels, not its loudness.

Comment: I think `[minimumVolume]` might refer to the lowest volume it can get to when someone is walking away from the source of the sound. I might be wrong, but it's what I understand it to be

Comment: Now that i have a couple of references to research from, it seems that Fabian was right about its purpose, i'm not sure where MY information came from, but it's nice to be informed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [german minecraft wiki](https://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/Befehl/playsound) (translated to english):

> If minimunvolume is missing, 0 (zero) will be assumed.

Comment: looking at the wiki, i realise that my original idea of the minvolume was wrong, but this is still the correct answer